# Meteorjs mup imagePort

Tags: meteor, mup

I wanna ask Meteorjs mup deploy ImagePort problem, I want to A to B in Image, I don't want 80/tcp, want to remove it.
because my apache is used Port 80.it will conflict. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZrqG.png)
And this is my mup setting.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz8js.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the port to the `ROOT_URL` as well, but that isn't the problem here.

You may have edited the mup config after doing the initial set up. Sometimes you need to do a `mup stop` followed by a `mup reconfig` to make sure the changes go up to the server. I have also found that simply wiping the host and starting again fixes it.